# setTimeOut cannot pass stream as parameter

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to create a spectrogram and I need the function to call itself, but setTimeOut doesn't accept the "stream" parameter that I need for the drawing function.
Here's my code (I know it's incomplete).

```
var yAxis=0;
var n=0;
var canvas = document.getElementById("can");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var context = new AudioContext();
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || 
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia;
var analyzer = context.createAnalyser();
var node;
var input;

function gra(){

navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true }, spect,error);
analyzer.fftSize = 1024;
}

function spect (stream) {

node = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
input.connect(analyzer);
analyzer.connect(node);
node.connect(context.destination);
var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyzer.frequencyBinCount);

if (n==2047){

    yAxis=yAxis+1;
    n=0;
    setTimeOut("spect()",10,stream);
} else {
    analyzer.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
    ctx.strokeStyle = frequencyData[n];
    ctx.moveTo(yAxis,n);
    ctx.lineTo(yAxis,n+1);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    n=n+1;  
    setTimeOut("spect()",10, stream);
}



}

function error () {

    alert("The action cannot be completed!")

}
```

Comment: [Like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) ...

Comment: Please, format your code properly and show how do you invoke `spect` function for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Typo. it should be `setTimeout` not `setTimeOut`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function reference to `setTimeout` instead of a string

```
setTimeout(spect, 10, stream);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is still not doing the drawing for some reason, though. I've changed the loop to:

Comment: while (n<2048) {
 if (n==2047){
 
  yAxis=yAxis+1;
  n=0;
  setTimeout(function(){
     spect(stream)
  },10)
 } else {
  analyzer.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
  ctx.strokeStyle = frequencyData[n];
  ctx.moveTo(yAxis,n);
  ctx.lineTo(yAxis,n+1);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  n=n+1; 
  
 }

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  spect(stream)
},10)
```

Or in es6 style)

```
setTimeout(() => spect(stream),10)
```